# C# webdriver: Issue with wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.TagName("tr"))); returning WebDriverTimeoutException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am working with the following html table,

```
<tbody role="rowgroup">
<tr data-uid="d4d2114f-2aaf-4498-977b-ae5b8c16618c" role="row" class="Standard k-state-selected" aria-selected="true">
<td role="gridcell" id="sublist-ComplianceTaskUserLinksSublist-sublist-grid-wrapper_active_cell" class="k-state-focused" aria-describedby="7f2be8c4-c05c-4959-8b6e-26f26ffd343c sublist-ComplianceTaskUserLinksSublist-sublist-grid-wrapper_active_cell">USER5</td>
<td role="gridcell">USER5 </td></tr>
</tbody>
```

There is only one row however this will not always be the case so i have wrote a method which identifies a rows data-uid based on a cell value which is,

```
IWebElement tablebody = LinkedUserGroupComplianceTaskUserLinkTable.FindElement(By.TagName("tbody"));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.TagName("tr")));
List<IWebElement> rows = new List<IWebElement>(tablebody.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));
IWebElement row = rows.Where(item => item.Text.Contains(loginname)).FirstOrDefault();
string rowid = row.GetAttribute("data-uid");
```

However when i run a test containing this method i get exception,

WebDriverTimeoutException

against `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.TagName("tr")));`

I have used the above method elsewhere with success.

I have added a thread sleep to the method instead of the line throwing the exception which when ran works - code below,

```
IWebElement tablebody = LinkedUserGroupComplianceTaskUserLinkTable.FindElement(By.TagName("tbody"));
Thread.Sleep(3000);
List<IWebElement> rows = new List<IWebElement>(tablebody.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));
IWebElement row = rows.Where(item => item.Text.Contains(loginname)).FirstOrDefault();
string rowid = row.GetAttribute("data-uid");
```

I'm looking for some help in how to refactor the method so i don't have to use the Thread.Sleep() or any suggestions as to why my original method is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by waiting for all cells to be visible  using the below,

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.CssSelector("td role = gridcell")));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to API documentation of `VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By)`:

> An expectation for checking that all elements present on the web page
>   that match the locator are visible. Visibility means that the elements
>   are not only displayed but also have a height and width that is
>   greater than 0.

I think you should try `PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By)` which checks for all elements present (but not necessarily visible) on the web page that match the locator.

Comment: Tried that still no joy - I have now got it working, will add the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already found an answer to your question. I was wondering if there were other tables on the page that were invisible. Using just the tag name to find an element or elements is very often not selective enough to get what you're using.

I was going to suggest By.XPath instead of by tag name. You could use something like:

```
IWebElement tablebody = LinkedUserGroupComplianceTaskUserLinkTable.FindElement(By.TagName("tbody"));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//tbody[@role='rowgroup']//td")));
// I'd prefer to put some way of uniquely identifying the table here
// but you only showed us the <tbody> element.
IWebElement row = LinkedUserGroupComplianceTaskUserLinkTable.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody[@role='rolegroup']/tr[@role='role' and contains(text(),'" + loginname + "']"));
```